# What do you pass for the cv parameter in the sklearn method cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

In sklearn, there is a method for cross validation called cross_val_score. One of the parameters of this method is 'cv'.

I understand in cross validation, there is no splitting the data into training and validation (70-30 split). Instead, you split the data into 'k' subsamples, then train it on the K-1 subsamples and validate using the kth sample.
And repeat it for each of the 'k' subsamples.

So is this cv = k, i.e the number of subsamples in which you split the training data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It determines the splitting strategy used by sklearn.

The default (“none”) is 3-fold CV.

[image]

[Doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)

Comment: So cv=k, the number of subsamples or folds,correct,?

Comment: Correct, the number of folds used in the stratified sampling.

Comment: @Victor, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) / [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) an answer if you think it has answered your question